# How do I set the font used by Fontconfig for generic font family names?

Tags: fonts, 17.04

I would like to use eg. "Roboto" for the font used whenever an application specifies `sans-serif`. My understanding is that this is decided by Fontconfig using rules in `/etc/fonts` and can be set on a user basis with `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/NN-customisations.conf` (where `NN` is `[00-99]`).

I have the following in `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/00-aliases.conf`

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
  <alias>
    <family>sans-serif</family>
    <prefer><family>Roboto</family></prefer>
  </alias>
  <alias>
    <family>sans</family>
    <prefer><family>Roboto</family></prefer>
    </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

However `fc-match` still shows `DejaVuSans.ttf` being used (even after reboot):

```
~ ☼ fc-match -s "sans-serif"
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
emojione-android.ttf: "Emoji One" "Regular"
DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Bold"
DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Oblique"
DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Bold Oblique"
Roboto-Regular.ttf: "Roboto" "Regular"
Verdana.ttf: "Verdana" "Regular"
Arial.ttf: "Arial" "Regular"
n019003l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Regular"
Loma.ttf: "Loma" "Regular"
...(many more)...
```

Roboto is down in 6th place!

How do I tell Fontconfig to use Roboto here?

Answer (score 3):

Try this config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family">
            <string>sans-serif</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
            <string>Roboto</string>
        </edit>
    </match> 
</fontconfig>
```

Comment: It works! That first `serif` should be `sans` though. how does the matching work? Will it also affect other fonts with "sans" in the name?

Comment: Just tested it on a few and no, it doesn't clobber other fonts with "sans" in the name. The apps I expect to use this do so correctly.

Comment: @detly: Good that it helped. I'm not the right person to explain it step by step. There are a few similar files installed in Ubuntu by default.

Comment: You're substituting `serif` fonts with Roboto which you shouldn't I think. Roboto is a sans-serif font and OP wanted it to be the default for `sans-serif` family only

Comment: @Anwar: So it seems; just removed the `serif` section. Thanks for heads up!

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I've seen other variants achieving same thing. For example, I am using this http://paste.ubuntu.com/24705437/ to set 'sans' family to 'Noto Sans'

Comment: @Anwar: Yeah, that's indeed sufficient for some font families. But the OP already tried that for Roboto, if I understood it correctly.

Comment: I think the problem is with the number `00`. That may have been overriden. Though I haven't tested. Need to test with other number

Comment: Tested it. Surprisingly that worked in my system! `fc-match 'sans'` and `fc-match 'sans-serif'` reported Roboto correctly!

Comment: @Anwar: So was it all based on a misconception then? (I think that a user specific config file overrides the files in `/etc/fonts/conf.d` irrespective of which prefix number you use. OTOH the prefix number matters if other user specific config files exist.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59512/discussion-between-anwar-and-gunnar-hjalmarsson).

Comment: @detly: Would be great if you could review the above discussion and comment on it.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson which part in particular? Changing the `00` prefix to something else/removing it?

Comment: @detly: Mostly the fact that Anwar tested with your original config file, and it worked for him.